# Application Settings key values pairs are swapped from Staging env to Production in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Application Settings key values pairs are swapped from Staging environment to Production environment in azure while swapping. I need application setting value for staging should be in staging environment and for production should be in production. how would I achieve that? , can we do that same through coding.

Or else how would do, slot identification from code instead of URL.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the **slot setting** checkbox:

> To configure an app setting or connection string to stick to a slot
>   (not swapped), access the Application Settings blade for a specific
>   slot, then select the Slot Setting box for the configuration elements
>   that should stick the slot. Marking a configuration element as slot
>   specific has the effect of establishing that element as not swappable
>   across all the deployment slots associated with the app.

[Source.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing)

[image]

Comment: Could you share the link  of C# code way. I am not familiar with PowerShell script Thanks Martin Branl